# Need help with changing text with combobox state change

Tags: actionscript-3, combobox

I have one text box and one combobox.

I want it such that when someone changes the combobox value, the text should change in the text field.

`priceText` is the name of text box

My code is below; it's not working:

```
var comboFar:ComboBox = new ComboBox();
addChild(comboFar);

var items2:Array = [
{label:"Arizona", data:"87.97"},
{label:"Colorado", data:"91.97"},
];

comboFar.dataProvider = new DataProvider(items2);

comboFar.addEventListener("change",testFar());

function testFar(event):void {

  priceText.text =event_obj.target.selectedItem.data;

}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you should use selectedIndex instead

```
priceText.text =event_obj.target.selectedIndex.data;
```

or

```
priceText.text =event_obj.target.selectedItem.label;
```

edit: hmm more I think about it...you might have it right, just
could you also try doing this as well?

```
comboFar.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE,testFar());
function testFar(e:Event):void {
  priceText.text =event_obj.target.selectedItem.data;
}
```

Comment: great, glad I could help out. which of the suggestions above work?

Comment: while the first two suggestions in this answer are correct, but the issue in your code is because addEventListener required a reference to callback function. See, Limitless's answer to see what I mean.

Answer (score 2):

In addEventListener, you are calling `testFunc()`. You need to pass function's reference instead like below:

```
import flash.events.Event;
comboFar.addItem({label:"Arizona", data:"87.97"});
comboFar.addItem({label:"Colorado", data:"91.97"});
comboFar.selectedIndex=0;
comboFar.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE,testFunc);
function testFunc(evt:Event):void {
    priceText.text =evt.target.selectedItem.data; // 87.97
    // or
    priceText.text =evt.target.selectedItem.label; // Arizona
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
priceText.text = (event_obj.target as ComboBox).selectedLabel;
//or
priceText.text = (event_obj.target as ComboBox).selectedItem.label; // replace "label" if there is another label field
```

But you should use bindings if this is Flex.

Comment: Iget this error
1136: Incorrect number of arguments.  Expected 1. and 1067: Implicit coercion of a value of type void to an unrelated type Function.